# Which equations can be solved by Boost C++ library’s ibeta_inva, ibeta_invb, and gamma_q_inva functions?

Tags: special-functions, inverse, gamma-function, applications, beta-function

All functions in this question are directly from [**this Boost C++ library page**](http://mtweb.cs.ucl.ac.uk/mus/arabidopsis/xiang/software/boost_1_47_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/perf/getting_best.html). These functions find the value of a random variable such that the distribution of the random variable equals a given probability, or the [quantile function](http://mtweb.cs.ucl.ac.uk/mus/arabidopsis/xiang/software/boost_1_47_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/perf/getting_best.html) for [Regularized Incomplete Beta](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) and [Regularized Incomplete Gamma](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedGammaFunction.html) distributions. These functions are also hard to calculate, so algorithms are used to evaluate them, but they still have applications in problem solving. Here are the definitions from Boost:

$$\text I_z(a,b)=\frac{\int_0^zt^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt}{\int_0^\infty t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt}=k\implies a=\text{ibeta_inva}(z,k,b),b=\text{ibeta_invb}(z,a,k)$$

and

$$Q(a,z)=\frac{\int_z^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt}{\int_0^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt}=k\implies a=\text{gamma_q_inva}(k,z)$$

For example:
$$\text I_{1-a}(x,3)=\frac12 a^x ((a^2-4a+3)x+(a-1)^2x^2+2)=k\iff (a-1)^2x^2+(a^2-4a+3)x+2-2ka^{-x}=0\implies x=\text{ibeta_inva}(1-a,k,3)$$

and

$$\text I_{1-a}(3,x)=-\frac12 a^x(-2ax^2+a^2x^2-4ax+a^2x+x^2+3x+2)-2=k\iff (a-1)^2 x^2+(a^2-4a+3)x+2+(2k+4)a^{-x}=0\implies x=\text{ibeta_invb}(1-a,3,k)$$

These quantile functions are implemented in  [scipy like here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.chdtriv.html#scipy.special.chdtriv) and not made up. Simpler cases of the ibeta_inva/ibeta_invb are the [W-Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and logarithm function. Boost gives little information on the domain and notation of these 3 functions.

However, I could find no other types equations which could be “solved” by using ibeta_inva/ibeta_invb except for $a^x+a_nx^n+…a_1x+a_0=0$. Additionally, I found no special cases of $Q(a,z)$ for which substituting a value for $z$ gives a simpler function and we can use gamma_q_inva to find the inverse.

What other equations are solved by gamma_q_inva, ibeta_inva, and ibeta_invb? Please correct me and give me feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has functions which are not fully recognized, but the question still has success, so here are applications:

Since the [Lerch Transcendent $\Phi(z,s,a)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Lerch+transcendent) and the Regularized Beta function are:

$$\lim_{b\to0} \text B(x,b) \text I_a(x,b)=a^x \Phi(a,1,x)$$

one can use Boost’s, and SciPy’s similar functions, ibeta_inva and equivalent ibeta_invb functions to solve for $x$ with a limit.

For gamma_q_inva and gamma_p_inva, there is only one possible application which is to solve for $n$ in the [exponential sum function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=exponential+sum+function) with the Regularized Incomplete Gamma function:

$$\text e_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}=e^x Q(n+1,x)$$

but this function is too specific and may not have any other applications. Also, see the question for reference. Please correct me and give me feedback!